# Send Credit card details to another server after customer enters card details in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment, knockoutjs, credit-card

How to send credit card details to another url outside of magento and get response token, after customer enters credit card details in checkout page.

Comment: You can use CURL for post CC detail.

Comment: In checkout we are using knockouts right.I need to know how we can send information in knockouts.

Comment: Use observer,  use sales_order_place_before event.